# Configure vim on MACOSX for ruby

Tags: ruby, vim

I am trying to configure `vim` for `ruby1.9`.
I have no `~/.vimrc` file for now. Should I create one? I have a `~/.viminfo` on my `Mac OSX`. Which one does `vim` read?

Any help configuring `vim`?

Comment: What are you trying to configure? ~/.vimrc is like ~/.bashrc, a script that's loaded once on startup. It's not necessarily the best place to put language specific configuration, but it kinda depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear enough. my vim has no syntax highlighting now for ruby 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, vimrc and viminfo are different files for different usage. Generally, vimrc contents configurations for vim behaviours. And viminfo is to store cut buffers persistently, and other things.  So if u would like to configure vim for ruby, I suggest put them in vimrc. But a better choice is to use vim plugins and modify them for your own convenience. And it has nothing to do with the OS platform.

Comment: ok, I found this, http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoUseVimWithRails, then this,https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails that says to do this, https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen and requires this "Install to ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim". now I do not have a ~/.vim/ directory. So is there any other simpler way please?

Comment: @TrtTrt This is the common way to install vim plugins. I guess it's the easiest way for any unix hackers. Just use 'mkdir' command to create a empty dir and use 'cp' command to copy all plugin files into this dir.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Find out if your version of Vim supports Ruby.**

   ```
   :echo has('ruby')
   ```

   The command above should return `1` if Ruby support is built-in and `0` otherwise.

   If the answer is `1`, you can proceed to step 3.

   If the answer is `2`, you should install a more complete Vim. Go to step 2.
2. **Install a better Vim.**

   You have a bunch of options: manually from [the sources](http://www.vim.org/download.php), via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), via [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) or the simplest, downloading [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

   - **MacPorts**

     Once MacPorts is setup, issue this command in your shell:

     ```
     $ sudo port install vim +huge +ruby
     ```
   - **Homebrew**

     Once Homebrew is setup, issue this command in your shell:

     ```
     $ brew install vim
     ```
   - **MacVim**

     Download and install.
3. **Ruby support**

   There's nothing to do.

You seem to have found what to do to add Rails support.

All the files and folders mentioned in tutorials must be created by you if they are not there: `~/.vimrc`, `~/.vim/`, `~/.vim/autoload`, etc.

Comment: Just for my information. Why the downvote?